# 1932 Finance board game

Tags: identify-this-game, monopoly

We inherited board games from my husbands grandmother who died in the 1980s.  Among them is a practically brand new (doesnt look used) board game called Finance.  The instruction booklet says copyright 1932. Some googling reveals that this was a precursor to Monopoly and was bought out by Parker Brothers a few yearslater. Do people collect old board games? Would this have some value?

Comment: Not sure the exact version you have or condition, but from the one google query I did, you can find others on the internet selling for $5-50.

Answer (score 3):

*Finance* was published by *Dave Knapp* and was one of the candidates to buy the patents of *Elizabeth Magie* who invented *The Landlord's Game*.

The other candidate was the company *Parker Brothers* which acquired the patents and turned *The Landlord's Game* into *Monopoly*.

If in good or even better mint condition, you'll get more than $50. As mentioned by *Nancy H* and I myself didn't find any version of the 1932' *Finance* (in comparision to the more common *Parker Brother* 36' and 58' publications) so you might want to get it curated.

Comment: I have searched some but all the ones I see are the Parker Brothers version. This one preceded it. But thanks for checking.